# Compare an array of hashes against each other, both ways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Adding this because some folks didn't see what I was asking for, but I'm looking for the unique values in each array, as compared to the other array.

I need to find the differences between `saved_start` and `incoming_start`, but also between `incoming_start` and `saved_start`. `saved_start` is the result of a db query while `incoming_start` is a result of `params` from a webhook. Here are the two arrays to start with:

```
saved_start = [{id: "12345", qty: 25}, {id: "678", qty: 20}]
incoming_start = [{id: "12347", qty: 25}, {id: "678", qty: 20}, {id: "abc", qty: 20}]
```

I find the differences between the arrays:

```
in_array = incoming_start - saved_start
saved_array = saved_start - incoming_start
```

The above returns:

```
in_array => [{:id=>"12347", :qty=>25}, {:id=>"abc", :qty=>20}]
saved_array => [{:id=>"12345", :qty=>25}]
```

And then iterate through them to find that `in_array` has the `id` of `12347` and `abc` while `saved_array` does not. While `saved_array` has the `id` of `12345` and `in_array` does not. And the same goes for the quantities.

This works well if the `in_array` and `saved_array` are the same size. If not it breaks.

```
in_array.each do |incoming|
  saved_array.each do |saved|
    pp "Does the saved hash have the id #{incoming[:id]} 
    #{saved.has_value?(incoming[:id])}"
    pp "Does the saved hash have the quantity of 
    #{incoming[:qty]} #{saved.has_value?(incoming[:qty])}"
  end
end
```

The above works well because `in_array` is larger than `saved_array`

The below returns bad data because `saved_array` is smaller.

```
saved_array.each do |saved|
  in_array.each do |incoming|
    pp "Does the incoming hash have the id #{saved[:id]} 
    #{incoming.has_value?(saved[:id])}"
    pp "Does the incoming hash have the quantity of #{saved[:qty]} 
    #{incoming.has_value?(saved[:qty])}"
  end
end
```

In english, I need to make `saved_start` contain the same data as `incoming_start`.

But to do this I need to know what is in `saved_start` that is NOT in `incoming_start` so I can delete it from `saved_start`. Then figure out what is in 'incoming_start' that is not in 'saved_start' so I can add it. And then finally which `id` is in both but maybe the `qty` is different in `incoming_start` so I'll need to update `saved_start`.

whew..

Thanks

Comment: Please post the desired outcome you expect to receive.

Comment: updated! please see the english at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Why not `saved_start = incoming_start`?

Comment: Because then I know there is a difference, but where is the difference? in `saved` or `incoming` ? And then also what values are different?

Comment: What I said is to assign `saved_start` with `incoming_start`. Not compare(`==`)

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need the input and expected output.

Comment: @Doguita I'm not sure I follow.. maybe an example? If I assigned one to the other, then they would be equal. Getting rid of any differences.. Yea I don't understand.. I've added this to the original post as well, but `saved_start` is the result of a db query while `incoming_start` is a result of `params` from a webhook.

Comment: Please just use `[1,2,3,4,5]` and `[4,5,6,7]` as example, and tell what the desired output should be. If it works for an Array of Integers, it will also work for other Arrays.

Comment: Or draw a nice, simple https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram

Comment: The question was posted more than two hours ago and no answers have been posted. That means that readers (myself included) don't understand the question.  Before the line, "I find the differences between the arrays:" you need to state the question in words and show the desired result for the example you have given.

Comment: @Eric, I don't know if that example is equivalent. Hash values may be central to the question (with emphasis on *may*). Todd, I don't see why the Rail's tag is relevant. Rails may have been used to obtain the two arrays, but the manipulation of those arrays would seem to be a pure Ruby question. Note that some readers may filter out questions with Rail's tags.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : The OP is doing set operations. For sets, only hash values are needed, not the actual object.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the likely answer to this question is by doing something else than simply array manipulation. I'm guessing that its an XY problem that is probably better solved by using the IDs from the incoming webhook to query the database and then performing a reject operation on the array of hashes.

Comment: @max: `reject` is then nothing else than set difference. There aren't so many possibilities. I dare say the answer will involve basic set operation (possibly XOR, -, & or +). For this, we still need more info from the OP.

Comment: I'll put this in the OP as well, but in one sentence.. I'm looking for the unique values in each array, as compared to the other array.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I hope the following code might help. this code will: (01)-Point values in Array 1 NOT found in array 2  ...  (02)-Point values in Array 2 Not found in Array 1  ...  (03)-Store all Unique Values in Array 2    ....  For the description of the question I think this is what you are looking for, to make thing easier I rename the arrays to: arr1 & arr2.

```
   #Compare an array of hashes against each other, both ways

saved_start = [{id: "12345", qty: 25}, {id: "678", qty: 20}]
incoming_start = [{id: "12347", qty: 25}, {id: "678", qty: 20}, {id: "abc", qty: 20}]

    # storing in an Array with easier name
p arr1 = saved_start
p arr2 = incoming_start
puts

    # Initialize array where the Non duplicated vales will be stored
not_in_arr_1, not_in_arr_2 = [], []


    # Check if the arrays are same
if (arr1 == arr2) == true then 
    puts "Arrays are equal" 

else
    puts "Arrays NOT Equals"

    # ----------------------------

        # Storing Values from array 1 not found in array 2
    arr1.length.times do |x|
        if arr2.include?(arr1[x]) == false then
            not_in_arr_2 << arr1[x]
        end
    end 

    # ----------------------------

        # Storing Values from array 2 not found in array 1
    arr2.length.times do |x|
        if arr1.include?(arr2[x]) == false then
            not_in_arr_1 << arr2[x]
        end
    end 

    # ----------------------------

        # concatenating original Array2 + values of Array1 not found in Array 2
    arr2.concat not_in_arr_2

    # ----------------------------

        # Console Printing Results
    puts 
    puts "Values in array 1, NOT found in array 2:"
    p not_in_arr_2
    puts

    puts "Values in array 2, NOT found in array 1:"
    p not_in_arr_1
    puts

    puts "Array 2 with updated values:"
    p arr2
    # ----------------------------

end

# ----------------------------------------
#       Test Run
# 
# [{:id=>"12345", :qty=>25}, {:id=>"678", :qty=>20}]
# [{:id=>"12347", :qty=>25}, {:id=>"678", :qty=>20}, {:id=>"abc", :qty=>20}]
# 
# Arrays NOT Equals
# 
# Values in array 1, NOT found in array 2:
# [{:id=>"12345", :qty=>25}]
# 
# Values in array 2, NOT found in array 1:
# [{:id=>"12347", :qty=>25}, {:id=>"abc", :qty=>20}]
# 
# Array 2 with updated values:
# [{:id=>"12347", :qty=>25}, {:id=>"678", :qty=>20}, {:id=>"abc", :qty=>20}, {:id=>"12345", :qty=>25}
# 
# ----------------------------------------
```

I Hope this helps. ;)